# Can't open ASP.NET site on POSready 2009 machine w/ IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, embedded, asp.net, windows-xp-embedded

When the site gets built, it autopublishes to a LAN location (10.x.x.x). I can reach this location no problem from my workstation. But when I try to go there from the POS machine (connected to the same LAN), I get "internet explorer cannot display the webpage" for some reason.

I am connecting through a port by the way. And so if I don't include http: first (it IS http, not https), IE8 seems to think 10.x.x.x is a protocol.

I can also connect to the root server 10.x.x.x without the port or further path, from the POS machine.

update: When trying to connect to the same site but hosted on a different server (albeit a somewhat older version of the site), it worked! So I'm investigating the host a bit further now and noticed it is lacking several system updates. Maybe it's a .NET framework piece that's missing? I'll know soon, after having updated.

Comment: Have you opened port 80 in your Firewall?

Comment: I can use other http sites, so I assume so. In the url, the port I use is 4xxxx something, but that's only incoming for the server, right?

Comment: Other local sites?

Comment: Yes. http://10.x.x.x:45744/URLA (which I want to reach) does not work, while http://10.x.x.x:45744/URLB works.

Comment: What protocol does it think it is exactly? Can your workstation ping the POSready 2009 machine?

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson: Are you able to install Firefox? Possibly even the portable version? Unfortunately IE is pretty useless for debugging these sort of problems.

Comment: @Ramhound If I try to enter for instance 10.11.12.13:42522/path it thinks 10.11.12.13 is a protocol. I can indeed ping the machine from my workstation.

Comment: @James Installed Firefox. It doesn't work either. Getting a "connection failed".

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson: Does it not give any more information other than that? Have you tried installing the Firebug add-on for Firefox (https://getfirebug.com/) ?

Comment: @DaveRook yes, I said so in the OP. But I may have been a bit unclear. It does work from my Windows 7 workstation on the same LAN.

Comment: I need to know which protocol it thinks it is.

Comment: @James no, it just looks like a standard error page. I have now installed Firebug.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson: Try opening Firebug then accessing the page. Firebug can be opened by pressing F12.

Comment: It could be that the site has blocked access to your IP. IIS allows you to set up a whitelist or blacklist of IP addresses for a site. This is set up under the Directory Security tab -> IP address and domain name restrictions.

Comment: @James Sure, it's up and running now. What am I looking for? It only displays the error page DOM...

Comment: The **Net** tab should show the request if you refresh the page. What does it say?

Comment: @James it shows an HTTP Get request that gets aborted. 0 bytes transfered. Regarding settings in IIS, the IP address and domain name section of Directory Security is greyed out. Maybe I need to be admin?

Comment: Update: My user is "computer administrator" on the server (actually Windows XP machine).

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson: Could you post a screenshot of the error you are getting in Firefox please?

Comment: It's possible that I am on my way towards finding a solution. See edit of OP. If that won't help, I'll be back with a screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, quite simply, that the hosting machine (running XP in this case) needed to update itself through Windows update. It is unclear what particular update was missing, as a batch was installed.